# how can i map two column in single rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How can i map two columns in single rails query.

Eg.

```
 @profiles = Profile.all.map(&:user_firstname)
```

After running this query i would able to get users_firstname form table(which is right).

But how can i add users_firstname and users_lastname in above query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can do:

```
@profiles = Profile.all.map{|p| "#{p.users_firstname} #{p.users_lastname}"}
```